# Modular arithmetic system $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ and $x \equiv -5 \pmod{22}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The task is to find all integers $x$ such that

$x \equiv 2\pmod 7$

$x \equiv -5\pmod {22}$

My guess is that the Chinese Remainder Theorem may help. I've never done a question like this that had a negative value in one of the equations before. If someone can show me how to solve this that would be great!

Comment: We use a trick. The first congruence can be rewritten as $x\equiv -5\pmod{7}$, so the solution to the system is $x\equiv -5\mod{(7)(22)}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Very clever! Since I can't vote your comment up, +1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the second equation, write $x = 22t - 5$. Then the first equation becomes
$$
\begin{align*}
22t - 5 &\equiv 2 \pmod{7}\\
t &\equiv 0 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore we have $t = 7s$. The general solution is $x = -5 + 154s, s\in \mathbb{Z}$. (We've used the congruences $22 \equiv 1$ and $7 \equiv 0$ modulo $7$. Though we didn't use it here, the Chinese Remainder Theorem actually told us in advance that there would be a unique solution modulo $154$.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. How did it tell _us in advance that there would be a unique solution modulo 154_?

Comment: When $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, any system of congruences $x \equiv a \pmod{m}, x \equiv b \pmod{n}$ has a unique solution modulo $mn$. That is exactly what the Chinese Remainder Theorem says.